# How to store, edit a variable in Application Scope in Mule

Tags: mule, mule-el

I want to store a variable in Application Scope in Mule, also i want to be able to update the variable.

Answer (score 2):

Hi add object store and enable overwrite option

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer from Mule Docs

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/storing-objects-in-the-registry

Comment: Hi add object store and enable overwrite option

Answer (score -2):

you able to use session variable (< set-session-variable variableName="nameOfTheVariable" value="somevalue"/>, https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/session-variable-transformer-reference), it can be used in any flow in application.

Comment: Session variables will be stored only for a particular session